# Swift 3 conversion - 'predecessor()' is unavailable

Tags: swift, swift3, xcode8

I am getting the above error. So how do we convert the following codes to swift 3 compatible?

```
let charactersAreInCorrectState = { () -> Bool in
            let previousContext = self.textDocumentProxy.documentContextBeforeInput

            if previousContext == nil || (previousContext!).characters.count < 3 {
                return false
            }

var index = previousContext!.endIndex      
            index = index.predecessor()
            if previousContext![index] != " " {
                return false
            }
```

Comment: Add more code please, I cannot understand what class has variable previousContext.

Comment: [Swift Evolution 0065 collections move indices](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0065-collections-move-indices.md)

Comment: @RomanPodymov i have updated the codes

Comment: `index = previousContext!.index(before: index)`

Comment: @LeoDabus It worked! thanks again!